# How do I verify my privacy on Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, privacy, tor

Based on my question, you can tell that I'm not experienced by any stretch of the imagination. However, I'm eager to learn.

I spent quite some time setting up a full node on a headless 2011 Mac Mini running Bitcoin Core full time. I also did my best to get everything running through Tor.

The point is I want to do my part to support the network, but at the same time I also want to avoid attracting any attention (from my provider, authorities, hackers, ...)

So here is my question: in what way(s) can I run checks to verify the privacy of my operation? Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Hi, one thing that may help for actual on chain privacy is looking at Blockstream explorer when you do a transaction, and looking at the bottom in the 'Privacy' section, heres an example of a tx with 'mixed script types' https://blockstream.info/tx/9d86441f0de05ca516e9a8ba0778c3c158ceba7756b7769d8ca351718f6acd5f . This gives you any privacy breaking heuristics they catch in your transaction, it can be helpful to discover privacy vulnerabilities in Bitcoin you were previously unaware of, as well as clue you in to how private the software you are using to transact really is trying to be.

Comment: @Poseidon i think he's talking about his node's privacy, not transaction privacy

Answer (score 1):

If you set up everything over tor (and perhaps i2p), and don't keep poiting to it in other places (e.g post your onion service on social networks). It's unlikely you'll get in any trouble. There's no trivial test to do in this situation.